# Unable to get uniq -c in while loop

Tags: linux, bash, count, uniq

I'm trying to sort a log file and get a total count of unique IP addresses and do something with the ones that appear > than n. this is my first command:

```
$ grep -B 1 "foobar" ip.log | grep "IP Address" > ip_count.log
```

which outputs:

```
IP Address    : 133.55.39.56
IP Address    : 116.243.70.151
IP Address    : 117.46.13.194
IP Address    : 115.179.82.10
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 13.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
IP Address    : 33.123.2.123
```

if i do this I get a proper count:

```
$ awk '{print $4}' ip_count.log | uniq -c
      1 133.55.39.56
      1 116.243.70.151
      1 117.46.13.194
      1 115.179.82.10
      9 13.123.2.123
      6 33.123.2.123
```

but if I do this I don't:

```
$ while read -r line ; do c=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}' | \
uniq -c | awk '{print $1}') ; if [[ $c -gt 1 ]]; then echo "$line" ; \
fi ; done < ip_count.log

1 133.55.39.56
1 116.243.70.151
1 117.46.13.194
1 115.179.82.10
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 13.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
1 33.123.2.123
```

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong within the loop, so maybe someone could tell me. there's probably some better way to combine all this into one command anyway, so any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're calling awk/uniq/etc. on a single line at a time...

Comment: Oh, so I need a `;` or something like that?

Comment: No... you need to pass all the (sorted) lines to one instance of uniq, like in your working code.

Comment: Move the uniq outside the loop: `while read ...; do ...; done < ip_count.log | uniq -c`

Comment: That works, but how would I check if the count of the ip address is greater than 1 within the loop? I don't really see what the loop would do for me rather than the command if I can't get the unique count within the loop.

Comment: @JackO'Leary Think about what's happening inside the loop. It reads, say, "`IP Address    : 33.123.2.123`", and runs `echo IP Address    : 33.123.2.123 | awk '{print $4}' | uniq -c ...`. So `uniq -c` receives just "` 33.123.2.123`", and since it only got it once it prints "`1 13.123.2.123`". Then the next iteration of the loop runs, gets the same `$line`, and so `echo -c` prints the same thing again. Since it's a completely new instance of `uniq -c` each time through the loop, they can't tell there's a bunch in a row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no loop is needed :

```
uniq -c ip_count.log | awk '$1 > 1 { print $1" "$5 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file in the loop, it executes command row by row.

```
awk '{print $4}' ip_count.log | uniq -c
```

In the above, all records are read from `stdin` and process.

when you execute loop `while read -r line` your variable `$line` only contains 1 record instead of the whole file.

You can do it in single awk command using an associative array.

An alternative solution using `awk`

```
$awk -F':' '{ count=1; a[$2]=a[$2]+count} END {for (i in a) if (a[i]>1 )print i, a[i]} '  ip_count.log
 33.123.2.123 6
 13.123.2.123 9
$
```

Explanation:

`-F':'` --> we are setting custom field seprator as `:`
`count=1;` --> Initialize a variable as default value 2
`a[$2]=a[$2]+count` --> Create a associative array with `$2` as index and count as values.
`END` --> Wait till `{ }` code block execution is complete
`{for (i in a) if (a[i]>1 )print i, a[i]}` --> Loop through each value in array

Also, it's a good practice to pass sorted input to `uniq` command.

For example:

```
$echo -e "a\na\nb\na"  
a
a
b
a
$echo -e "a\na\nb\na"  | uniq -c
      2 a
      1 b
      1 a
$echo -e "a\na\nb\na"  | sort | uniq -c
      3 a
      1 b
$
```